# runtime_version versus runtime-version in cloudml-samples/flowers/sample.sh

Tags: google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

In Google's sample code found at [cloudml-samples/flowers/sample.sh](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/flowers/sample.sh), between lines 52 and 64, is the argument "runtime_version":

```
# Training on CloudML is quick after preprocessing.  If you ran the above
# commands asynchronously, make sure they have completed before calling this one.
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training "$JOB_ID" \
  --stream-logs \
  --module-name trainer.task \
  --package-path trainer \
  --staging-bucket "$BUCKET" \
  --region us-central1 \
  --runtime_version=1.0 \
  -- \
  --output_path "${GCS_PATH}/training" \
  --eval_data_paths "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/eval*" \
  --train_data_paths "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/train*"
```

Shouldn't "runtime_version" be replaced with "runtime-version" to avoid an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I've submitted a [PR](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/pull/30) (in the future, never hesitate to do so yourself)